# What should I use to build RTSP server, should it be vlcj or xuggler?

Tags: java, rtsp, xuggle, vlcj

I have a plan to develop RTSP streaming server with java. Now I have to decide with library used to decode media and stream data in rtp format. I am looking into vlcj and xuggler for video decoding and streaming. I did some research about differences of these library but I cannot make a decision yet. So I would like to ask you guys if I want to build a server which provide following feature. Do you think which one is better?
1. can stream video on demand to multiple users
2. can receive stream in mms format and restream it to rtsp format

Initially, I try ffmpeg and ffserver but there is audio out of sync problem so I decide to make my own server. the good way to use vlcj is to use out-of-process but I am afraid about performance in video on demand. I think about xuggler but I am afraid that it will have the same problem as I have in ffmpeg.

Could you throw me your opinion which one is appropriate on this situation?

Answer (score 1):

With VLCJ (or Xuggler) depend that the machine has run the necessary libraries installed. Also, personally, I could not do a pilot with VLCJ Streaming server (and I've tried for a long time).

Java SE provides a framework called JMF (Java Media Framework) for developing, among other things, a streaming server

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-140239.html

This framework is not the best there is, but it's work.

As a final note, I can say that I have developed a streaming server in Java with JMF, you can see it here http://code.google.com/p/servidor-streaming-rtp-rstp-java/ to give you a reference.

Regards!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As for as I know JMF is outdate so I don't consider to use it